# How to fix "interstitialAd.IsLoaded() returns true in offline" (unity C#)

Tags: unity-game-engine, return, admob, offline, interstitial

interstitialAd.IsLoaded() is always returning true even if device is offline. its works fine when app device is online.

```
public class InsAdBanner : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int SceneIndex;
    private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;


    void Start()
    {
        this.RequestInterstitial();
    }

    void RequestInterstitial()
    {
        string interstitial_ID = "ad_id";
        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(interstitial_ID);

        if (this.interstitialAd != null)
        {
            this.interstitialAd.Destroy();
        }

        this.interstitialAd.OnAdLoaded += HandleOnAdLoaded;
        this.interstitialAd.OnAdFailedToLoad += HandleOnAdFailedToLoad;
        this.interstitialAd.OnAdOpening += HandleOnAdOpened;
        this.interstitialAd.OnAdClosed += HandleOnAdClosed;
        this.interstitialAd.OnAdLeavingApplication += HandleOnAdLeavingApplication;


        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

        interstitialAd.LoadAd(adRequest);
    }

    public void Display_InterstitialAD()
    {
    <!-- plz see this line below -->

        if (interstitialAd.IsLoaded())
        {
            Debug.Log("interstitialAd " + interstitialAd.IsLoaded());
            interstitialAd.Show();
        }
        else {
            getOut();
        }

    }

    public void getOut() {
        interstitialAd.Destroy();
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneIndex);
        restertAdCounter.restertsAdCouner += 1;
    }

    #region Interstitial callback handlers

    //Handle event

    public void HandleOnAdLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdLoaded event received");
    }

    public void HandleOnAdFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args)
    {
        RequestInterstitial();
    }

    public void HandleOnAdOpened(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdOpened event received");
    }

    public void HandleOnAdClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneIndex);
    }

    public void HandleOnAdLeavingApplication(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneIndex);
    }

    #endregion

    void OnDisable()
    {
        this.interstitialAd.OnAdLoaded += HandleOnAdLoaded;
        this.interstitialAd.OnAdFailedToLoad += HandleOnAdFailedToLoad;
        this.interstitialAd.OnAdOpening += HandleOnAdOpened;
        this.interstitialAd.OnAdClosed += HandleOnAdClosed;
        this.interstitialAd.OnAdLeavingApplication += HandleOnAdLeavingApplication;
    }

        void OnDestroy()
    {
        interstitialAd.Destroy();
    }
}
```

I expecting it to return false in offline..it is working fine when app device is online .. but creates this problem when device is offline..plz help.. i cant find any solution in google.

Edit: Its not working on online too.. after adding real ad in place of test ad this problem is occurring.

Comment: Are you testing it on a real device? Do you get any errors? When do you turn off the internet connection when testing?

Comment: tnq for your reply.. yes i am using it on a real device.. it worked fine when i was working with test ad.. now when i connect real ad.. its not working...not even in online its not working now. its always true. in online mode ads are not showing.

Comment: With real ads you need to publish the game first. It may also take a while before the ads start working.

Comment: but even when device is offline why interstitialAd.IsLoaded() is always returning true? is there a way to fix this?.. plz help

Comment: Sorry, it is hard for me to say. Maybe someone else will answer you.

Comment: tnx for trying :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved** my problem by changing *Minify->Relese->Proguard* to *Minify->Relese->None* on player setting.(Although i dont know how actually its working)